# How to control which rows are editable in MudTable?

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

Is there a way to define some condition for MudTable so rows which doesn't correspond it will not be editable?

Comment: What is an "editable row"? Show some code.

Answer (score 1):

By using RowStyleFunc you can disable the click on a row with css.

```
<MudTable RowStyleFunc="@_disableRowClick" ...
```

with _disableRowClick

```
private Func<Element, int, string> _disableRowClick => (x, i) =>
{
    string style = string.Empty;
    //condition for the row to be disabled
    if (x.Name == "Argon")
    {
        style += "pointer-events: none;";
    }

    return style;
};
```

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mawxvFQhetFqcQqN

There is a pull request ongoing, adding the possibility to add IsEditable to rows https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/pull/7787