# MudBlazor editable DataTable or Grid

Tags: mudblazor, editablegrid

I would like to make some rows of editable DataTable or grid to readonly state depending on the values of its one or more cells of it, please?
I have tried to row property `RowClass` but it was useless.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77554590/how-to-control-which-rows-are-editable-in-mudtable. The same works for a datagrid aswell https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cEGIaHmOdEbjMHRV